# Django rest framework validate pagination limit and offset

Tags: python, django, pagination, django-rest-framework

Django Rest Framework by default swallows the exception raised for invalid [limit](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/pagination.py#L338) and [offset](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/pagination.py#L350) values even if they are not integers and returns the default limit and offset values.
 
Also there is no `min_offset` and `min_limit` thus it allows negative values in limit and offset. 
I need to throw error on those cases in my API. 
I have built a custom pagination class overriding the `paginate_queryset` method and made my validations there. Is there an API to validate the minimum limit and minimum offset values. I have the below code where I validate it by myself.

Is it ok to write validations for paginator inside the method as there is no mention of it from the docs or do I need to validate inside my viewset methods itself?

```
class CustomPagination(pagination.LimitOffsetPagination):
    default_limit = 25
    max_limit = 50
    min_limit = 1
    min_offset = 1
    max_offset = 50

    def paginate_queryset(self, queryset, request, view=None):
        limit = request.query_params.get('limit')
        offset = request.query_params.get('offset')

        if limit:
            limit = int(limit)
            if limit > self.max_limit:
                raise serializers.ValidationError({"limit" : ["Limit should be less than or equal to {0}".format(self.max_limit)]})
            elif limit < self.min_limit:
                raise serializers.ValidationError({"limit" : ["Limit should be greater than or equal to {0}".format(self.min_limit)]})
        if offset:
            offset = int(offset)
            if offset > self.max_offset:
                raise serializers.ValidationError({"offset" : ["Offset should be less than or equal to {0}".format(self.max_offset)]})
            elif offset < self.min_offset:
                raise serializers.ValidationError({"offset" : ["Offset should be greater than or equal to {0}".format(self.min_offset)]})

        return super(self.__class__, self).paginate_queryset(queryset, request, view)
```

Comment: I was wondering if my answer was helpful for you

Comment: @John Moutafis Yes. I asked them back in DRF IRC channel and they said the decision is intentional and it's upto the developer to validate it.

Comment: Good to hear @xtreak :D! Care to accept the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at DRf code on [`LimitOffsetPagination`](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/pagination.py#L319) you will see that it utilizes two methods to parse `limit` and `offset`:

- [`get_limit()`](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/pagination.py#L357):

  ```
  def get_limit(self, request):
      if self.limit_query_param:
          try:
              return _positive_int(
                  request.query_params[self.limit_query_param],
                  strict=True,
                  cutoff=self.max_limit
              )
          except (KeyError, ValueError):
              pass

      return self.default_limit
  ```
- [`get_offset()`](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/pagination.py#L370):

  ```
  def get_offset(self, request):
      try:
          return _positive_int(
              request.query_params[self.offset_query_param],
          )
      except (KeyError, ValueError):
          return 0
  ```

As you can see the possible exceptions are handled inside those two methods.

Therefore you can easily override those methods and there is no need to reinvent the wheel either. 
Make the methods catch the exception and `raise` it again:

```
class CustomPagination(pagination.LimitOffsetPagination):
    default_limit = 25
    max_limit = 50
    min_limit = 1
    min_offset = 1
    max_offset = 50

    def get_limit(self, request):
        if self.limit_query_param:
            try:
                return _positive_int(
                    request.query_params[self.limit_query_param],
                    strict=True,
                    cutoff=self.max_limit
                )
            except (KeyError, ValueError) as e:
                raise e  # Re-raise the caught exception

        return self.default_limit

    def get_offset(self, request):
        try:
            return _positive_int(
                request.query_params[self.offset_query_param],
            )
        except (KeyError, ValueError) as e:
            raise e  # Re-raise the caught exception
```

---

**Note:**
Although the aforementioned works, it will be extremely inconvenient for your application to crash every time a user passes an erroneous argument to it and you should consider using it.